# Visual Studio does not detect Package folder for Unity

Tags: git, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am preparing a Unity project to be shared with others. According to [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html), I should share `Assets`, `Packages`, and the `ProjectSettings` folders.

However, Visual Studio (I'm using ver 2019) does not recognize `Packages` folder, it does not show up in the Git Changes window during the initial commit. While `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` are recognized and added.

Is there a way I can manually add the `Packages` folder to the files to be staged?

Comment: Well, I managed to upload that manually to force them into the repo... But still, I would like to know if there's a way to let Visual Studio recognize the `Packages` folder

Comment: Do you happen to have a .gitignore file which excludes the Packages folder?